# MDX Calculation speed - CurrentMember?

Tags: mdx

I am still getting to grips with MDX and I am looking for some help. Here is my MDX query:

```
 CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Fake]
   AS 
   IIF(
    (
      (
        [Sales Data].[Ship-to No].CurrentMember
       ,[Sales Data].[Price Type].&[Core]
       ,[Measures].[Sales - Local Currency]
      ) 
    / (
        [Sales Data].[Ship-to No].CurrentMember,
        [Sales Data].[Price Type].[(All)].[ALL],
        [Measures].[Sales - Local Currency]
      )
    ) > 0.9 
  ,1 
  ,NULL
  ), 
VISIBLE = 1; 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Test Calc]
  AS 
  SUM(
     Descendants(
       [Sales Data].[Ship-to No].CurrentMember
      ,[Sales Data].[Ship-to No].[Ship-to No]
     ),
    [Measures].[Fake]
  ), 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

SalesData is the fact table and the basic calculation is to count the number of customers that have sales of more than 90% of the price type "Core".

The query currently takes around 5 seconds to complete but I think this can be faster if I don't use CurrentMember according to http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2008/07/29/product-volatility-optimizing-mdx-with-mdx-studio.aspx

But I don't know where to begin in changing this, can anyone help me make this more efficient?

Comment: aggregations designed? row counts? MOLAP? adequate hardware?

Comment: @MitchWheat, Aggregations have been designed using the wizard (I am allowing the usage to build up first) The fact table has roughly 20M rows and it's using MOLAP. Sorry should have put this on the post. Hardware - Currently only on developer SQL server so on local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete currentmember from the first measure does it make any difference?

```
 CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Fake]
   AS 
   IIF(
    (
      (
        [Sales Data].[Price Type].&[Core]
       ,[Measures].[Sales - Local Currency]
      ) 
    / (
        [Sales Data].[Price Type].[(All)].[ALL],
        [Measures].[Sales - Local Currency]
      )
    ) > 0.9 
  ,1 
  ,NULL
  ), 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

In respect of the currentmember you use in the second measure maybe EXISTING will suffice:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Test Calc]
  AS 
  SUM(
    EXISTING [Sales Data].[Ship-to No].[Ship-to No].MEMBERS
    ,[Measures].[Fake]
  ), 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

Comment: That works it knocked a whole second off, thank you very much it's very much appreciated and it's simpler to read as well